# how to check if all values of list are in another list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list for example `ls1=['one', 'three']` and another list for example `ls2=['one', 'two', 'three']` I want to check if all elements of ls1 are in ls2.

Comment: probably the most simple & most efficient method is to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set): `set(lst1) <= set(lst2)`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Thanks The answer worked and is the best

Comment: if `lst1=[1,2,3]` and `lst2=[5,6,7]` @hiroprotagonist

Comment: @Epsi95 ...then what? what is your criticism? (note: i am using `set` not `len`).

Comment: Oh sorry, my apology :)

Comment: @Epsi95 no worries! have a nice weekend!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Probably they are refering to the fact that there is no short-circuit in that approach. `set(lst1)` will always iterate the entire list, even when you could possibly break after the first element. No asymptotic complexity change in the general case, but still should be considered.

Comment: @schwobaseggl agreed. the best-case complexity is worse in the `set`-approach. i'd argue that the average and worst-case complexity is better tough...  (+1 for your answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set.issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) to check whether all the elements in the set are present in other. For example:

```
ls1 = ['one', 'three']
ls2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']

set(ls1).issubset(ls2)
# returns: True
```

If all element of `ls2` will be present in `set(ls1)`, `set(ls1).issubset(ls2)` will return `True`, else will return `False`.

You can also perform the `issubset` operation using `<=`:

```
set(ls1) <= set(ls2)
# returns: True
```

By the way, for using `<=`, both the arguments needs to be of `set` type.

Whereas in `set(ls1).issubset(ls2)`, we are only converting `ls1` to set , because `.subset()` can accept `list` (without the need to type-cast to `set`).

Comment: The `issubset` version is still longer than the `<=` version, despite the latter's conversion...

Comment: It's on one's personal preference. Some prefer functional approach whereas other prefer operational. You can choose the version you like

Comment: Believe `set` is faster approach.

Answer (score 1):

For repeated contains checks you should definitely convert `ls2` to a `set`:

```
s2 = set(ls2)

check = all(x in s2 for x in ls1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with the `all()` function:

```py
ls1=['one', 'three']
ls2=['one', 'two', 'three']

# all() function only returns True is all the items in ls1 are in ls2
check = all(elem in ls2 for elem in ls1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print (list(set(ls1) ^ set(ls2)))
```

Output:

```
['two']
```